# Is there a way to disable the track pad?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

My computer has a track pad pad. I use mousekeys and a computer mouse, and I never use the track pad. Is gets bumped frequently, and I want to just turn it off.

Is there any way to completely disable the track pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm away from a Windows 10 laptop at the moment to test, but here are the approximate steps :

1 ) Click Windows menu -> Settings gear -> Devices -> Trackpad on the left.

2 ) On the right, there should be a toggle switch to disable the trackpad.

Since you're using a mouse as well, it should be straightforward to toggle it back on again later if needed.  Windows 10 Settings is also designed to be usable from the keyboard only, using Tab, right-left-up-down arrows, and Enter key.

Specific makes/models may not work this way.  You may have to look in the system tray by the clock to see the controls for the trackpad.  Hover over to see the text descriptor of each icon.  Right-click to summon a menu, and some of them respond to double-clicking.  Each of these types of controls will be unique, so you will have to explore a little to find the proper setting.

Comment: Using the touchpad icon worked.