# How to disable a malfunctioning track pad

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, touchpad

The touchpad of my laptop (HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop) is malfunctioning. I don't like using it anyway so have no problem with it not working, but it occasionally causes the mouse to move or click randomly.

I'd like to disable it.

Things I've tried that don't work:

- Uninstalling the driver (or at least the only mouse driver that isn't my USB mouse)
- [Settings menu, trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/1403350/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-track-pad) (Option does not exist in the menu)
- Looking at the system tray (trackpad isn't there)
- [Disable through mouse properties](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03882926) (Touchpad tab doesn't exist)

Things I'd rather not try:

- Opening the case to fix/remove it (I'd rather not risk it)
- Sending it for repair (I can't afford to be without this laptop for the 3 weeks PC World takes).

Answer (score 0):

Some more ways of disabling the touchpad:

- Your BIOS/UEFI might have an option for
  "Touchpad" or "Internal Pointing Device" that could be set to Disabled.
- In *Settings > Devices > Touchpad*, uncheck
  "Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected".
- In Device Manager, find the touchpad, right-click it and select
  "Disable device"
- Use `regedit` to navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\Status`
  and set the registry item `Enabled` to `0`.
- For a Synaptics touchpad, use `regedit` to navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh`
  double-click `DisableIntPDFeature` and set it to `33`.
  Now in *Start > Settings > Devices > Touchpad > Additional settings >
  Device Settings* you should see a new option
  "Disable internal pointing devices when external USB pointing device is attached".
- A third-party utility is the free
  [Touchpad Blocker](https://touchpad-blocker.com/).
- If all else fails, sabotage the touchpad by giving it in Device Manager
  a completely wrong driver of a non-touchpad device.
  Create a System Restore point before doing that, in case of problems
  with Windows.

A reboot might be required.